# asp.net: How to update data in GridView through Checkbox in particular row

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, webforms

I am developing a Web Form, where I show Gridview with data. One of the column consists of CheckBox. How can I update data in particular row.

so my question is:

How to unidentified particular row and send an sql request with UPDATE when user Check or Uncheck the CheckBox?

Update:
Here is my code that i have. It doesn't update value of CheckBox.
namespace:

```
public partial class Call_Bills : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    string check;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button_Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
         {
             con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDeductionsConnectionString2"].ToString();
             con.Open();
             bool private1 = (row.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked;
             if (private1 == true)
             {
                 check = "1";
             }
             else
             {
                 check = "0";
             }
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into DetailCosts(private) values(@private)", con);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@private", check);
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }}
```

name of GridView is: GridView2;
name of Checkbox in the Table: private;
id of CheckBox in Gridview is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Private" SortExpression="private">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("private") %>'  />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You can google "CommandName" and "CommandArgument" and start from there.

Comment: User will not press any buttons to check the Checkbox, it should be dynamically

Answer (score 0):

you can manually define a method to handle a postback generated by a control inside a gridview column. To do that you just need to add the tags `AutoPostBack=True` and `OnCheckedChanged=YourMethodName` to the control.

On the code-behind, define this method as public void, and define the parameters that usually would be there (sender as object and e as EventArgs), like:

```
public void YourMethodName(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

On the method, you may need to get the GridViewRow which contains the control that has generated the event. To do that, just parse the sender parameter (which will be the checkbox) and get 2 parent levels (GridViewCell and GridViewRow), it would be something like:

```
GridViewRow row = ((CheckBox)sender).parent.parent;
```

Since you have the row, you may get any control inside it with the FindControl method. If you need an id to identify the entitiy being updated, you may store it in a hidden field inside the row.

Hope it helps!